# How to get specific dynamic Input Hidden values for each comment on jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to delete a comment by comment id but I can only get the value of the first comment

```
<?php foreach($comment as $comments): ?>

    <div id="commentsection">
            <div class="note">
                <h5><?= $comments->c_content; ?></h5>
            </div>
            <input 
                type="hidden" 
                class="form-control" 
                id="commentid" 
                name="commentid" 
                value="<?= $comments->id; ?>">  

            <h5><i class="fa fa-user text-success"></i> 
            <?= $comments->username; ?> | <?= $comments->c_datetime; ?> 
            <?php echo ($username == $comments->username ? '
              | <a href="" id="delete-comment">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a>' : '' ) ?></h5>                                        
        </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

this gets the commentid's of each comment and I want to get the comment_id of the specific comment on clicking of delete-comment with onclick event

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#delete-comment').click(function(){
   var commentid= $(this).parent().siblings().find('input[name="commentid"]').val();
});
```

Your selected comment id will store in `commmentid`